# Fill etched glass door number with paint

Tags: doors, glass

Above our front door is a clear glass panel which has been etched on the inside with our house number and the etching coloured black.

Over the last 20 years the colour has slowly faded so the house number is no longer visible to anyone passing by, which is causing issues with deliveries.

Has anyone got a good way of re-colouring the etched portion without leaving marks on the clear glass? My idea is to use a squeegee to wipe a line of thick paint across the etching and then clean the surrounding glass, but I would welcome a better method.

Comment: Can we assume the etching has texture, but no depth?

Comment: @ChrisH thats correct. I believe it was sand blasted, so its rough but not deep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a production shop environment, the paint/squeegee method would make a lot of sense. Speedy for mass production.

For one number over one door to be done in place:

1. Block door so nobody knocks over your ladder
2. Clean out the faded paint remnants (as that's what's going to show outside, since this is etched on the inside)
3. Put on calm music
4. Grab a paintbrush - a small artist brush
5. Paint patiently
6. Let dry
7. Clean up any paint on the non-etched glass with a razor scraper

Comment: +1 when I saw "block door"! I'd add, masking with appropriate tape can help a lot to maximize speed and to minimize item 7, particularly if there are any straight edges to the numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @Ecnerwal. That seems like a straight forward method.